# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="username"]"} error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

When I am login page then find these error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
> element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"[id="username"]"}   (Session info:
> chrome=93.0.4577.63)
>
> C:\Users\avesh\Desktop\text>[6672:6336:0901/120328.999:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [12:03:28.999] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
> descriptor fr m node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)
> [6672:6336:0901/120329.103:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(214)]
> [12:03:29.103] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1048 Failed to read
> descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is
> not functioning. (0x1F)

**my code is**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass

username = input("name:")

password = getpass("Enter your password")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:\\av\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login")

username_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("user_pass")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*button[contains(., 'Login')").click()
login_buttion.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you enter value for elements in the window, you need to allow Selenium to be able to find the elements. Many times, the elements need some time to appear on the page ( may be due to ajax or network latency).

So you need to wait for some time, for which Selenium provides the functionality of `Waits`.

Read more about implementing different types of wait here - [Link](https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html)

You can modify you script as

```
from selenium import webdriver
from getpass import getpass
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

username = input("name:")

password = getpass("Enter your password")

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="C:\\av\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'username')))

username_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username_textbox.send_keys(username)

password_textbox=driver.find_element_by_id("user_pass")
password_textbox.send_keys(password)

login_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='btn  btn-primary']")

login_buttion.submit() ## or login_button.click()

driver.quit()
```

Also, one more thing, I have been to this website multiple times, and once you add the details, there is a captcha that appears, without which this login details won't be accepted.

So, you would also need to solve for the Captcha that is being used on the page.

Comment: anyone tell if read captcha read by sound and automatic fill in textbox. how ?

Comment: You cannot do that. The whole point of having a CAPTCHA on the web page is that it cannot be automated by a machine. There are libraries that may help you out, but that is doubtful.

Comment: A captcha shall appear, you have to extract the text in the captcha using the sound of the captcha provided on the website. LInk:-https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login

Comment: when add anything character in username captcha will be apear

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are trying to get a user name input, and then try to send that username into the UI, I have optimized your code with few validation points, such as if user does not give anything and there's one more validation which you can modify is that (username should be more than 4 chars) :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

username = input("name:")
user_name = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "username")))

if username == "":
    print("user name was not entered correctly")

if len(username) > 4:
    user_name.send_keys(username)
```